# How many nonisomorphic simple regular planar connected graphs are there with $v$ vertices, $e$ edges and $f$ faces?

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra

It seems to me that, for $v = 6$, $e = 12$ and $f = 8$, the regular octahedron (dual-cube) is unique with such properties.

I am interested mainly about uniqueness of simple 4-regular planar connected graphs. If with these conditions and specified $v$, $e$, $f$ the uniqueness is not warranted, I don't want to figure out exactly how many such graphs there are.

Comment: Have you tried [looking in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=regular+planar+connected+graph&language=english&go=Search)? For example, according to https://oeis.org/A072552, there is indeed only one (simple) planar connected 4-regular graph with v=6 vertices, but there are three with v=10 vertices.

Comment: Thank you, Noam Zeilberger. Indeed, this sequence answers the main part of my question, about the regular octahedron.

Comment: This seems to answer the whole question, since once $v$ is chosen, then $e$ and $f$ can be deduced. That is, $e$ is given in terms of $e$ (by the handshaking lemma) and $f$ is given in terms of $v$ and $e$ (by Euler's formula). The sequence reflects that uniqueness is not warranted.

In fact, these graphs seem to be the duals of planar quadrangulations.

Comment: Your title asks for "How many...", yet your questions ends with "I don't want to figure out exactly how many...". Are you interested in finding $v$, $e$, $f$ for which there is a unique such graph? Or do you want to know the number of graphs given $v$, $e$ and $f$? Also note that the degree $d$ and number of vertices $v$ together determine $e$ and $f$.

Comment: There are many interesting Questions that might be asked about counting planar graphs with a certain number of edges and vertices, and their difficulty in answering will vary.  Please consider making the Question more precise.